# Prepend a row to a table

Tags: knockout.js, signalr

I am using signalr to prepand a row to a table, but I could not do it:

HTML:

```
<div>
    <table>
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <td>Name</td>
                <td>Price</td>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody data-bind="foreach: Products">
            <tr>
                <td><span data-bind="text: name"></span></td>
                <td><span data-bind="text: price"></span></td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

Knockout:

```
function ProductViewModel() {
    Products = ko.observableArray();

    Products.unshift(
    {
       name: Products.name,
       price: Products.price
    }
);
}
ko.applyBindings(new ProductViewModel());
```

SignalR:

```
chat.client.hello = function (product) {
       console.log(product.name);
       ProductViewModel.Product(product);
};
```

Comment: What is not working and happens instead? Do you get any errors?

Answer (score 0):

It should look something like this:

```
function ProductViewModel() {
    var self = this;
    self.Products = ko.observableArray();
    self.AddProduct = function(product) {
        self.Products.unshift(product);
    };
}

var productViewModel = new ProductViewModel();
ko.applyBindings(productViewModel);

chat.client.hello = function(product) {
    console.log(product.name);
    productViewModel.AddProduct(product);
};
```